# Newspaper3k export to csv on first row only

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, newspaper3k

With the help of 'Life is complex' I have managed to scrape data from CNN newswebsite. The data (URLs) extracted from are saved in a .csv file (test1). Note this had been done manually as it was easier to do!

```
from newspaper import Config
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import ArticleException
import csv

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'

config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = USER_AGENT
config.request_timeout = 10

with open('test1.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_file = file.readlines()
    for url in csv_file:
        try:
            article = Article(url.strip(), config=config)
            article.download()
            article.parse()
            print(article.title)
            article_text = article.text.replace('\n', ' ')
            print(article.text)
        except ArticleException:
            print('***FAILED TO DOWNLOAD***', article.url)
            
with open('test2.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    headers = ['article title', 'article text']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'article title': article.title,
                     'article text': article.text})
```

With the code above I manage to scrape the actual news information (title and content) from the URLs and also to export it to a .csv file. Only the issue with the export is, is that it only exports the last title and text (therefore I think it keeps overwriting the info on the first row)

How can I get all the titles and content in the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for giving me a shout out.

The code below should help you solve your CSV write issue.  If it doesn't just let me know and I will rework my answer.

P.S. I will update my [Newspaper3k overview document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) with more details on writing CSV files.

P.P.S. I'm current writing a new [news scraper](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newshound), because the development for Newspaper3k is dead. I'm unsure of the release date of my code.

```
import csv
from newspaper import Config
from newspaper import Article
from os.path import exists

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'

config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = USER_AGENT
config.request_timeout = 10

urls = ['https://www.cnn.com/2021/10/25/tech/facebook-papers/index.html', 'https://www.cnn.com/entertainment/live-news/rust-shooting-alec-baldwin-10-25-21/h_257c62772a2b69cb37db397592971b58']
for url in urls:
    article = Article(url, config=config)
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    article_meta_data = article.meta_data

    published_date = {value for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'pubdate'}
    article_published_date = " ".join(str(x) for x in published_date)

    file_exists = exists('cnn_extraction_results.csv')
    if not file_exists:
        with open('cnn_extraction_results.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            headers = ['date published', 'article title', 'article text']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'date published': article_published_date,
                             'article title': article.title,
                             'article text': article.text})
    else:
        with open('cnn_extraction_results.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            headers = ['date published', 'article title', 'article text']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers)
            writer.writerow({'date published': article_published_date,
                             'article title': article.title,
                             'article text': article.text})
```

Comment: The code worked beautifully! I'll check often for the new news scraper! Nice work.

Comment: @RobbieVoort I will drop you a message here when it is done. What features do you need? What news sources did you need to query? Here is my current list of [predefined source](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newshound/blob/master/predefined_extraction_sources.md).